# How to do BATCH file complete directory copy and find the user temporary directory?

Tags: windows, windows-7, batch-file

How to do this in Windows? e.g: cp -R /tmp /var/tmp

```
: How to copy?
: cp -R this /var/tmp?
set temp=%USERPROFILE%
echo %temp%
copy thisWholeDirectoryIncludingSub/*.* %temp%
```

Comment: http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html, http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `xcopy` with `/e`: "Copies directories and subdirectories, including empty ones."

You may also want `/h`: "Copies hidden and system files also."

```
xcopy thisWholeDirectoryIncludingSub %temp% /e /h
```

Comment: great. But what i was trying to get is the temporary directory like in java i can have System.getenv("TEMP"); how do i get this similar using BATCH?

Comment: @Google - by using the `%envVar%` syntax, just as you did:  `%temp%`.  (Just don't overwrite `temp` first, as it should already exist by default.)